# how to fix the indexing error and to scrape the data from a webpage

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape data from a webpage from a wayback machine using pandas. I used string split to split some string if its present.

the URL for the webpage is [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140528015357/http://eciresults.nic.in/statewiseS26.htm?st=S26)

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

url =  "https://web.archive.org/web/20140528015357/http://eciresults.nic.in/statewiseS26.htm"
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

df = dfs[0]

idx = df[df[0] == '\xa0Next >>'].index[0]
# Error mentioned in comment happens on the above line.


cols = list(df.iloc[idx-1,:])
df.columns = cols

df = df[df['Const. No.'].notnull()]
df = df.loc[df['Const. No.'].str.isdigit()].reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')

df['Leading Candidate'] = df['Leading Candidate'].str.split('i',expand=True)[0]
df['Leading Party'] = df['Leading Party'].str.split('iCurrent',expand=True)[0]
df['Trailing Party'] = df['Trailing Party'].str.split('iCurrent',expand=True)[0]
df['Trailing Candidate'] = df['Trailing Candidate'].str.split('iAssembly',expand=True)[0]


df.to_csv('Chhattisgarh_cand.csv', index=False)
```

The expected output from that webpage must be in csv format like[image: Output]

Comment: pandas is not a perfect tool for scraping, consider using Beautiful Soup, you can try ```pandas.read_html()``` method, but my exprience tells me it is not perfect, it may produce an imperfect ```df```.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Sid the error is `    return getitem(key)
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Comment: Please explain what exactly is being accomplished/required in `idx = df[df[0] == '\xa0Next >>'].index[0]`

Comment: I used that to iterate into pages if a number of pages where available using index value. Since there is only a single page available the page values are not displayed.

Comment: Vignesh, there are 8 rows in the df[0], none of which get even close to the required data.

Comment: sid, I used that code to scrape the data from[link](http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises26.htm)2018 data. now I'm using the same code to scrape data from the past i.e 2014 data. But I couldn't

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeautifulSoup to extract the data. Panadas will help you to process the data in efficient way but its not ment for data extraction.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
response = requests.get('https://web.archive.org/web/20140528015357/http://eciresults.nic.in/statewiseS26.htm?st=S26')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
table_data = []
required_table = [table for table in soup.find_all('table') if str(table).__contains__('Indian National Congress')]
if required_table:
    for tr_tags in required_table[0].find_all('tr',{'style':'font-size:12px;'}):
        td_data = []
        for td_tags in tr_tags.find_all('td'):
            td_data.append(td_tags.text.strip())
        table_data.append(td_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(table_data[1:])
# print(df.head())
df.to_csv("DataExport.csv",index=False)
```

You can expect result like this in pandas dataframe,

```
                0   1  ...       6                7
0        BILASPUR   5  ...  176436  Result Declared
1            DURG   7  ...   16848  Result Declared
2  JANJGIR-CHAMPA   3  ...  174961  Result Declared
3          KANKER  11  ...   35158  Result Declared
4           KORBA   4  ...    4265  Result Declared
```

Comment: why is pandas not efficient given you are importing and using anyway? Genuine question

Comment: Buddy, pandas is much efficient for data processing buts its not ment for data extraction.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should get you the table on your url link ("Chhattisgarh Result Status") using a combination of BS and pandas; you can then save it as csv:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

url =  "https://web.archive.org/web/20140528015357/http://eciresults.nic.in/statewiseS26.htm?st=S26"

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
elect = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(elect,"lxml")
res = soup.find_all('table')
df = pd.read_html(str(res[7]))
df[3]
```